# How to cause an infinite loop in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

```
class DrawPane extends JPanel
{
  //size is the size of the square, x and y are position coords
  double size = 1, x = 0, y = 0;
  double start = (-1) * size;
  public void paintComponent(Graphics shape)
  {
    for(x = start; x <= scWidth; x += size)
    {
      shape.drawRect((int)x, (int)y , (int)size, (int)size);

      //When a row is finished drawing, add another
      if(x >= scWidth)
      {
        x = start; y += size;
      }

      //Redraws the entire grid; makes the for loop infnite
      else if(y >= scHeight)
      {
        x = start; y = start;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm confused as to why JPanel refuses to work with the loop once I make it infinite. How would I go about allowing it to do so?

Answer (score 3):

When you make the loop "infinite" you effectively tie up and freeze the Swing event thread preventing Swing from doing anything. Instead use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to drive your animation.

e.g.,

```
class DrawPane extends JPanel {
  //size is the size of the square, x and y are position coords
  double size = 1, x = 0, y = 0;
  double start = (-1) * size;

  public DrawPane() {
    int timerDelay = 200;
    new Timer(timerDelay, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            x += size;
            if (x >= scWidth) {
                x = start;
                y += size;
            }
            if (y >= scHeight) {
                x = start;
                y = start;
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }).start();
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)   {
    super.paintComponent(g); // Don't forget to call this!
    g.drawRect((int)x, (int)y , (int)size, (int)size);  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The paint function is supposed to update the Paint and get out of the way. You really shouldn't be putting in complex logic and definitely not infinite loops there.

Just do what you have (except get rid of the reset stuff that makes your loop infinite) and put `repaint()` in an infinite loop (preferably with some timer logic) somewhere else in your program.

Answer (score 0):

It will never break out of the paintComponent loop and update the GUI. The GUI will only update once the paintComponent method finishes. If you want to make the loop infinite, you need to take the code out of your event handler and be calling repaint() from elsewhere, possibly using a timer to do so.